# NextJS - Google font is not loading or displaying on the website

Tags: reactjs, fonts, next.js, tailwind-css, google-fonts

Followed the documentation and added a _document.js file with the provided code:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

When I use my chrome extension font checker and verify in the inspector, it states that it using the defaults fonts. Any idea how I can get this to work? Might there be some interference with the fact that I'm using tailwindcss?

Comment: have you already defined that font on tailwind.config.js?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in **globals.css**

```css
/* Google Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kurale&display=swap');

/* From Public Directory */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Kurale';
  src: url('/fonts/Kurale.ttf');
  font-style: medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you! I had forgotten to set this in my globals.css sheet.

Comment: This will work indeed. however, it's not recommended to use critical @imports in CSS because it will render the font after the page is already loaded.

I'd recommend you to use illia-chill's solution which is loading the font using Vercel's https://fontsource.org/. It is the most optimal way to load fonts with Next.js.

Comment: Caution with bootstrap or another frameworks css. Because they can conflict and not apply the font.

Comment: Yes you're right!

Answer (score 5):

1. Check [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization), use <style data-href= instead of
2. For the fonts with `NExtJS` and `Vercel` I recommend you to use [fontsource](https://fontsource.org/)

Answer (score 5):

Import all fonts in the globals.css or in the stylesheet imported in _app.tsx

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kdam+Thmor+Pro&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap");
```

> All the fonts had to be imported **separately**. For me, importing them
> all together didn't work in the production.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this **problem** a few minutes ago and **fixed** this by just adding one line of code.

Make sure you've added `display: "swap"` in your code like this -

```
const poppins = Poppins({
subsets: ["latin"]
weight: ["100", "200", "400", "700"],
display: "swap",
});
```

after adding `display: "swap"`, it started working.

Comment: can you tell me what is this line used for? its working perfectly but idk how, thanks anyway. Edit, i found the answer: "
This comes in the form of a CSS descriptor called font-display . By providing a value of swap , we tell the browser to render the page right away with fallback fonts, and then redraw the page once the fonts have loaded"  - https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/using_web_fonts#:~:text=This%20comes%20in%20the%20form,once%20the%20fonts%20have%20loaded.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the issue was caused by NextJS font optimization. It turned the href to data-href on the `<link>` tag on the client. I only had to turn the config option off to get it working:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  optimizeFonts: false,
}
```

https://nextjs-ja-translation-docs.vercel.app/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#disabling-optimization

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `<link>` try using `@import` in your `globals.css` (or any stylesheet which is imported to the `_app.js`):

```css
/* globals.css */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300;400;700&display=swap");
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the usual things worked for me.
I was trying to import the following in the global.css file:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700&display=swap");
```

and the font wasn't loading. I had to inject the actual font instead:

```css
/* IMPORTANT: For some reason directly importing the font from fonts.googleapis.com/css2 is not working. Instead I had to inject its contents */
/* @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700&display=swap"); */

/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Hp2ywxg089UriCZ2IHTWEBlwu8Q.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Hp2ywxg089UriCZOIHTWEBlw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Cp2ywxg089UriAWCrCBamC3YU-CnE6Q.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Cp2ywxg089UriAWCrCBimC3YU-Ck.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Cp2ywxg089UriASitCBamC3YU-CnE6Q.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DM Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/dmsans/v11/rP2Cp2ywxg089UriASitCBimC3YU-Ck.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: This helped me track down a solution to my problem. We are using CSP and I had `fonts.gstatic.com` in `font-src` but not `fonts.googleapis.com` in `style-src` -- thanks!